# “Hierba” vs. “yerba”: ¿está equivocado el DPD?

Tags: dialectos, fonología, yeísmo

En este [excelente artículo sobre el yeísmo](https://www.delcastellano.com/historia-yeismo-y-ll-igual/), [Javier Álvarez](https://twitter.com/delcastellano) explica que los orígenes del fonema /ʝ/ (que es la pronunciación estándar mayoritaria de lo que escribimos como *ll* o *y*) están en la /j/ latina, en ciertas secuencias de consonantes + *yod* y ocasionalmente en la diptongación de una *e* corta inicial (como en *yegua* < *equa*). Y después dice lo que motiva mi pregunta:

> Recordemos que «hierba» normalmente la escribimos con ‹hie‑›, pero
>   también la podemos escribir ‹yerba›, sobre todo cuando hablamos del
>   mate (...)

Esto me sorprendió porque, a mi entender y al menos en mi dialecto rioplatense, *hierba* y *yerba* son dos palabras claramente diferentes y no dos variantes ortográficas de la misma palabra. El DPD [concuerda](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=y7avlny9uD6xqSaWLI) con Álvarez, sin embargo.

> En los países del Cono Sur se emplea la grafía *yerba* para designar
>   las hojas de la planta denominada *yerba mate* (...)

(Nótese que dice "grafía", no "pronunciación".)
Si bien no sé exactamente cuál es el sonido con que pronuncio *hierba*, sí sé que no es el mismo que el de *yerba*. La gente a la que le pregunto me dice lo mismo. El único inconveniente es que no hay mucha base de comparación porque la palabra *hierba* es poco habitual en la zona rioplatense, salvo en usos especializados, y allí su pronunciación podría estar influenciada por la escritura.

Lo anterior vale para palabras como *hielo*, *hierro*, *hiena*, etc. (siguiendo la lógica del DPD, *hiena* y *llena* deberían ser homófonas, pero en rioplatense, al menos, no lo son).

¿Se equivoca el DPD? ¿Hay dos fonemas en rioplatense donde casi todo el resto del castellano utiliza uno? ¿Se pronuncia realmente *hiena* como *llena* en otros dialectos yeístas?

Comment: La diferencia entre /j/ y /ʝ/ es para mí aún más pequeña que la de entre /nj/ y /ɲ/ y en dialectos no yeístas la de entre /lj/ y /ʎ/.  Y fíjate que la diferencia entre  /nj/ y /ɲ/ es tan pequeña que Antonio + ito = Antoñito sin llamarnos la atención.  Querría pensar que en la mayoría de los casos *hiena* y *llena* sería más o menos iguales en la pronunciación, pero que *llena* podría salir con más fricción (creo que en todo dialecto el fonema /ʝ/ varía entre pronunciaciones con más o menos fricción) mientras *hiena* quedaría con su forma semivocálica, pero tendría que prestar más atención

Comment: ¿Qué tal si te grabas para mostrarnos la diferencia entre, por ejemplo, *hierba* y *yerba*, en aislamiento y en frases? // Creo que el contexto es lo que hace la diferencia entre *hierba* y *yerba*: en la cocina se usan *hierbas de olor*; los cabritos del cuento de hadas buscan *hierba tiernita*; y todo el mundo sabe que en Argentina es popular la *yerba mate*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He leído que la claridad de la distinción varía entre diferentes regiones según la pronunciación de *y* y *ll*:

> The greater the phonetic distance between the
>   strongest realization of **ʝ** and a pure palatal glide in the dialect, the greater
>   the likelihood of speakers establishing a separate category for words spelled
>   with a vowel.

("[Quasi-Phonemic Contrasts in Spanish](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a4b5/a4dc9e4ac376b6f3138a7de5e0077a45566e.pdf)", José Ignacio Hualde, p. 12)

Según Hualde,

> Rather than being optional, as in Castilian, in Argentinean consonantal
>   realizations [of **ʝ**]  are obligatory. For instance, whereas in Castilian *yo* ‘I’ may be
>   realized as [jó] ~ [ʝó] ~ [ɟó] depending, perhaps, on degree of emphasis, in
>   Argentinean only obstruent allophones are found: [ʒó] ~ [ʃó]. On the other
>   hand, in Argentinean Spanish the production in this consonant in words
>   with orthographic *hiV* is stigmatized as indicating “low educational level”.
>   In Standard Argentinean Spanish now [ʒ] ~[ʃ] contrasts with [j]. We find
>   [ʒ] ~ [ʃ] in *yeso, llena, tramoya, cebolla* but [j] ~ [ʝ] in words spelled with
>   (h)i such *hiel, hiena, paranoia*. There is even a minimal pair from what
>   originally was a single word with two alternative spellings: *yerba* **ʒérba**
>   ‘mate’ vs. *hierba* **jérba** ‘grass’.

(p. 12)

Pido disculpas por haber citado una fuente en inglés; no hablo español.

Comment: ¡No, pues, te salió muy bien, hombre!  From the Spanish you did write, I wouldn't have known you aren't a Spanish speaker!

Comment: @aparente001: Gracias. ¡Es la magia de los diccionarios y Internet! :)

Comment: Muy interesante el trabajo citado. Especialmente la constatación de que la diferenciación (o no) entre los fonemas en cuestión no es necesariamente una alternativa sí/no, sino un espectro.

Comment: @pablodf76 - For sumelic: Very interesting work you cited.  Especially the thesis that differentiation (or lack thereof) between the relevant phonemes is not necessarily a binary yes-no thing, but rather a spectrum.  (Pablo if I got anything wrong please chime in.)

Answer (score 2):

Tras leer lo que dice el DPD con el contexto que me dan tu pregunta y la respuesta de [sumelic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31101/13628), lo que entiendo que dice el DPD es:

1. **En general**, se acepta la grafía "yerba" como alternativa para "hierba".
2. **En el Cono Sur en particular**, la grafía "yerba" se refiere *exclusivamente* a las hojas de la *yerba mate*; es decir, no se usa como grafía alternativa, sino que se reserva para esa planta en particular.

El punto 2 solo aplica al Cono Sur; en el resto de zonas hispanohablantes aplica el punto 1. Así es como lo he entendido.

No estaría el DPD, por tanto, dándole la razón a Javier Álvarez; o no del todo. Mientras este afirma que la grafía "yerba" usada para hablar del mate es una simple grafía alternativa de "hierba", dando a entender que sería válido también usar "hierba" para lo mismo, el DPD lo que establece es una exclusividad de "yerba" sobre "hierba" para esa zona y significado concretos.

Nótese también que el DPD no entra en el tema de la pronunciación; solo indica que "yerba" así escrito se usa para algo muy concreto, no dice en ningún caso que se pronuncie igual que "hierba".
Al hilo de esto, entiendo que *yerba* lo pronuncias con `[ʒ]` o `[ʃ]`, ¿correcto? Tu ejemplo con *hiena ~ llena* me ha confundido un poco...

Comment: En efecto, *yerba* = [ʃeɾβa]. Y de la misma manera (porque *ll* siempre se pronuncia igual que *y*, eso sí), *llena* = [ʃena], pero *hiena* = [jena].

Comment: El asunto es que el DPD, al no hablar de pronunciación, justamente parece decir que la diferencia o variación es sólo en la escritura.