# "Hierba" or "Yerba" - which is the correct spelling?

Tags: ortografía

I've seen it spelled "Hierba" most of the time; occasionally spelled "Yerba".

Comment: Grammar is not concerned with the spelling of individual words (beyond that spelling reflecting the correct conjugation or inflection of a word).

Comment: [“Hierba” vs. “yerba”: ¿está equivocado el DPD?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31100)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't agree with the other answers. "Yerba" is not an alternative spelling for "hierba." In the Southern cone of South America we use "hierba" to mean "fine grass" and reserve the term "yerba" to refer to a special plant (yerba mate) whose leaves we use to prepare a special, typical tea.

The etymological origin may be the same and "hierba" is certainly a hyperonym, but "yerba" is a distinctly differentiated hyponym.

To endorse my point that, at least in the Southern cone of South America, "yerba" is NOT another spelling for "hierba", [in ASALE's Diccionario de Americanismos](https://www.asale.org/damer/yerba) we can read that "yerba" is a specific plant, not just a variant of "hierba":

> **yerba.**
>
> I.    1.  f. Ch, Py, Ar, Ur. Hojas deshidratadas y trituradas del árbol
> yerba mate que se utilizan para preparar el mate, infusión.
>
> 2. Py, Ar. yerba mate.

I found Gorpik's answer particularly interesting in that it mentions the famous song by Serrat (those of us who love "mate" would not object to the metaphor of the loved one's name tasting like "yerba mate"). My impression is that the spelling of "hierba" with "y" is infrequent (and nonexistent in these countries). Here's a RAE tweet I found which refers to its minority usage:

[image: Yerba]

Comment: Maybe the term "South America" is too wide: I am not sure if this is the only meaning  in Colombia or Venezuela (for instance), where mate infusion is not so common.

Comment: What is wrong to me is this assertion, even if taken from a dictionary:  La palabra hierba, escrita "yerba" en los países de Sur América (Argentina, Chile, Paraguay y Uruguay), viene del latín herba. We don't write "yerba" to mean "hierba."

Comment: As another inhabitant of the Southern Cone, on the Chilean side, I confirm that this is, indeed, the common use here; although I always thought that the "Y" spelling _is_ simply a variation on the "Hi-" spelling.

Comment: I don't know if "I don't agree with the other answers" is the way to go unless you have reliable sources outside your anecdotal evidence. The actual RAE dictionary shows "yerba" as an alternate spelling of "hierba", the "diccionario breve de mexicanismos" shows yerba as an alternate term for marujiana or used for cooking herbs, etc. This means that different countries MAY have different ADDITIONAL uses for "yerba" but, in general, it's an alternate spelling of hierba.

Comment: @terdon I edited my answer to reply to the comments above.

Comment: @kirgod Idem above.

Comment: Thank you! OK, so at least in those four countries, that seems clear. It is a little misleading that you're only quoting the first two definitions though. The rest of the entries make it quite clear that the use varies a lot by country and some, including some South American countries, use it in common terms like _yerba mala_. So it _is_ an alternative spelling, it just isn't one in the specific dialects of Ar, Ur, Py and Ch.

Comment: @terdon I only quoted the two acceptations of "yerba" when used alone (and obviously left out one that referred to a spider!). As for the combinations, the spelling does in fact vary, but we will never say something like, Estoy sentado sobre la yerba (to mean, I'm sitting on the grass). The famous book by Walt Whitman will never be found to be entitled "Hojas de yerba" but "Hojas de hierba". In my experience, "yerba" may only be used in some compound words.

Comment: And the famous movie with Warren Beatty and Nathalie Wood is "Esplendor en la hierba" (NOT Esplendor en la yerba, which would make me laugh out loud).

Comment: The specific plant used to make the beverage seems to be Ilex paraguariensis https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilex_paraguariensis

Comment: That is the scientific name.

Answer (score 3):

**Ambas son validas / Both are valid**

---

Algunas respuestas generales;

- *La grafía hierba es la más generalizada en la lengua culta; pero **también es válida la variante yerba**: «Descalzos sus pies para recibir el rocío que todavía impregnaba la yerba»*

*Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*

https://www.rae.es/dpd/hierba

- ***¿Por qué entonces se escribe yerba?*** *La palabra hierba, escrita "**yerba**" en los **países de Sur América** (Argentina, Chile, Paraguay y Uruguay), viene del latín **herba**. Muchas palabras latinas que tienen una **e** en la primera sílaba, transforman esa **e** en **ie** cuando pasan al español*.

*Por ejemplo*;

*ferrum -> hierro //   servus -> siervo //  tempus -> tiempo.*

*Etimología de yerba*

http://etimologias.dechile.net/?yerba

Comment: the e > ie shift isn't to do with the first syllable, but to do with the stressed syllable

Answer (score 3):

The current [entry in the DLE](https://dle.rae.es/yerba) spells the difference: *yerba* is an alternate spelling for *hierba* and, additionally, the name of the *yerba mate*.

We can find an example for the alternate spelling in *Tu nombre me sabe a yerba*, a well known song by Joan Manuel Serrat. But, even if that is the original title, it is so unusual that many people write *Tu nombre me sabe a hierba* and there are several covers of the song which use that spelling.

In summary: the *yerba mate* is almost always written *yerba*, and *yerba* can also be used as an alternate spelling for *hierba*, even though it is not so usual.

Answer (score 1):

Se nota que no hay una página separada en Spanishdict para ''yerba'', pero dice que se puede escribir ''yerba'' en lugar de ''hierba''.

Mi impresión es que la hierba es la que crece en un césped o un prado mientras que la yerba es ''herb'', pero podría depender de la región.

Comment: El lenguaje español tiene 23 academias reguladoras del lenguaje. Spanishdict no es una de ellas. Es más confiable utilizar diccionarios de estas academias (el más conocido siendo el de la RAE) para ver sobre ortografías alternas y regionalismos.

Answer (score 1):

hierba= grass, plant, pasture.

yerba= a specific tea from South America

Comment: That seems to duplicate information already in other answers. Can you edit and expand it to give sources?

Answer (score 0):

Hierba is a vegetal phytogeny (not herbs but exactly weeds) while Yerba is the processed product of the Mate plant which are actually bushes not a tree or weeds.

Comment: It is quite hard to understand this. I do not think phytogeny is the right word at all. Why do you think grass is a weed (=plant in the place where the gardener did not want it.) And finally the yerba plant is technically a tree although its growth starts of rather shrub-like.